# How to import javascript code into my c# program from a file?

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I am currently working on a c# programm using cerfsharp. In this program I need to be able to control awebbrowser. I do that executing javascript commands which are written as strings in my c# program. Everything works just fine however, as my projects grows, I need more and more strings to store my javascript code. A large part of my code concists only of strings which is not practically maintainable. I would like to be able to write all of my javascript code in a separate file and import it into my code so I won't have so many strings. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: File.ReadAllText

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way ..

```
@if (someCondition)
{
<script>
..
</script>
}
```